# embedded firebird 2.5 >> DBX Error: Driver could not be properly initialised

Tags: delphi, firebird, dbexpress

i'm try to connect to firebird 2.5 Embedded version(win32) with Delphi XE , I get the error when a click Test Connection

[image]

any help?

Comment: Make sure that dbxfb.dll and the correct fblient.dll are found. The IDE will not find it in the exe path when that is not also in the search path.

Comment: thanks, i copied dbx4fb.dll and fbclient.dll to "Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\8.0\bin" and now working well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LibraryName and VendorLib should be in search path

copy LibraryName "i'm using dbx4fb.dll  from   https://sites.google.com/site/dbxfirebird/home" and 
VendorLib "fbclient.dll founded in firebird directory\bin" to the search path "for delphi xe : Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\8.0\bin"